# Is there any file size limit to transfer data from Storage Transfer service in GCP(Amazon S3 to google cloud)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-data-transfer

I am transferring data from Amazon s3 to google cloud using storage transfer service. Is there any file size limit for the transfer ?

Comment: How do you do the transfer?

Comment: @zabop Data transfer service

Answer (score 0):

Here is the doc that states the limits and quotas about storage transfer.
https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/known-limitations-transfer